# Splitting A Game Texture Into Quadrants In The Node Editor?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, texture-coordinates

This game texture has four different tint masks in the alpha layer:

[image]

Is there any way to access them one by one in the node editor? I could edit the textures manually but a node solution would be easier in the long run

---

I've tried this node setup below:

[image]

I'm not sure why this attempt doesn't work but it somehow delivers the same tint mask except mirrored (mirrored mesh/UV) on outputs 1+2 and 3+4 respectively. So this is effectively only returning 2 out of the 4 masks and I don't understand why.

If I only use one output of the above group node, one of the tint masks is correctly applied to only *half* the mesh.

Comment: How is placed the UV map here?

Comment: I took a whack at this the other day and came up short, I'm gonna try again tonight, I think.